# django autofield, inheritance, manytomanyfield and ... no save

Tags: python, django, inheritance, subclass, manytomanyfield

I've a **Class** with a `ManyToManyField` and a **SubClass** with an `AutoField` **subID**. Django saves the `ManyToManyField` instances with the value of the **subID** and not, as one would expect with the value of the `Class` primary_key. Like this:

```
class Class( models.Model ):
    products= models.ManyToManyField( Product )

class SubClass( Class):
    subID= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Lets assume lowest id for class is 15 and lowest `subID` for  `SubClass` is 3.

```
sc= SubClass()
sc.save()
print sc.id, sc.subID

===> 16, 4
```

So far so good. Now add a product:

```
p= Product()
p.save()
print p.id

===> 77

sc.products.add(p)
sc.save()

print sc.products.all()

===> []
```

???
Thats not good. What happened?

```
dbms> select * from myapp_class_subclass where class_id = '4';
                                                           ^
id     class_id   product_id                               |
na     4          77                                       |
       ^                                                   |
       |                                                   |
       +------------------------+--------------------------+
                                |
         I used the subclass subID, not the class id.
```

So the final question: Did I miss something here? Is there a fault in the approach?

For the curious: In the real thing I'm using more `subClass's` and I need the `subClass` instances to have a unique number within that subclass. Furthermore I need to be able to query all `subClasses` at once. To solve this, I'm now using a self-made autofield but, I don't like that (DRY, KISS, etc) and furthermore it probably is not thread safe (yet).

So if any pythonista/djangonista has an idea how to use the existing `Fields` to do this please let me know.